# docker cant' access to mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

i'm trying till 3 days to create a db from docker compose.
I already done the procedure on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but on OSX catalina i'm having a some troubles.

```
version: "3.2" 

services:
  view-mongodb:
    image: xxxx/view-mongodb:3.6
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.db == true
    volumes:
      #- /opt/mongodb-data:/data/db
      - /Users/danilo/configurazione-view-locale/maria-db-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - view-network
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" 
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "50M"
        max-file: "10"

  view-mariadb:
    image: xxxxx/view-mariadb:10.2
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.db == true
    volumes:
      #- /opt/mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /Users/danilo/configurazione-view-locale/maria-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/VIEW_MYSQL_ROOT_PWD
    secrets:
       - VIEW_MYSQL_ROOT_PWD
       - VIEW_DB_PWD
    networks:
      - view-network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" 
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "50M"
        max-file: "10"

networks:
  view-network:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.10.0/24

secrets:
  VIEW_MYSQL_ROOT_PWD:
    external: true
  VIEW_DB_PWD:
    external: true
```

first of all if i want to mount the volume on /opt/mongodb-data docker can't write the file there, i already try to give permission using `chown 777` but it's not working.
So i changed the path (works) and when i have to exec the container using

```
docker exec -it <ID container> sh /opt/init.sh
```

i have this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I opened using sh the init.sh and verify that the path of the secret works (i used also the direct message)

there are the secret that i used, maybe i understand something but, i repeat, the process works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
$ echo "view-mariadb" | docker secret create VIEW_DB_HOST -$ echo "3306" | docker secret create VIEW_DB_PORT -$ echo "view" | docker secret create VIEW_DB_VIEW -$ echo "webstudio" | docker secret create VIEW_DB_DOK -$ echo "view" | docker secret create VIEW_DB_USER -
```

`echo "password" | docker secret create VIEW_MYSQL_ROOT_PWD -`
`echo "password" | docker secret create VIEW_DB_PWD -`

Someone can help? (I censored the name of the images because they own my company)